# How to implement Python functools.wraps equivalent?

Tags: go, functional-programming

I know I can wrap functions in Go through returning function, bug how to implement Python functools.wraps equivalent in Go? How to attach attribute to functions in Go? Like the code below in Python.

```
from functools import wraps

def d(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        f(*args)

    return wrapper

def d_wraps(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
        f(*args)

    return wrapper

@d
def f(a=''):
    print a

@d_wraps
def g(a=''):
    print a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'function name: ', f.__name__
    f('abc')

    print 'function name: ', g.__name__
    g('abc')
```

`d` does not change function name, `d_wraps` changes function name. The result is

```
function name:  wrapper
abc
function name:  g
abc
```

I want to use the wrapped function as key at runtime. So I want to keep the function name unchanged after wrapped. How to implement the job that `d_wraps` does in Go?

Answer (score 1):

> How to attach attribute to functions in Go?

No, You can not attach attribute to functions in Go.

> How to implement the job that d_wraps does in Go?

You can implement another function call your functions, and call the function with the new name.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
   g_warp("abc")
}

func g(a string){
   fmt.Println(a);
}

func g_warp(a string){
   g(a+"_mysuffix");
}
```

If you want to change the function content but use the same function name, you can use global function variable:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    g = gV2
    g("hello")
}

var g = gV1;

func gV1(a string){
    fmt.Println(a)
}
func gV2(a string){
    gV1(a+"_suffix")
}
```

If you have a lot of functions to have the same wrap logic, you can pass in the origin function and return the new function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    g = wrap(g)
    g("hello")
    f = wrap(f)
    f("hello")
}

var g = gV1;

func gV1(a string){
    fmt.Println(a)
}
var f = fV1;

func fV1(a string){
    fmt.Println(a+" "+a)
}
func wrap(originFn func(a string)) func(a string){
    return func(a string){
         originFn(a+"_suffix")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. @bronze man. But I think this method works only if I have a few functions. I manually write a new functions for each function. But if I have plenty of functions and I want to use wrappers, I need the function name not changed after wrapped. I want to use the function as key at runtime.

Comment: If you want to change the function content but use the same function name, you can use global function variable, see my code example in the post.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work if gV2 is simple. But I just check my code, the gV2 is a function with about 30 lines of code, which is a little complex. Not easy to write a gV2 for each function. So I think I still need to use wrappers.

Comment: If you have a lot of functions to have the same wrap logic, you can pass in the origin function and return the new function, see my code example in the post.